# DTO's in Django Python?

Tags: python, .net, django, standards, solid-principles

So I am starting to learn Django, and looking to build a Rest API with it. I am basically coming from .Net background.

I know that the Python conventions are quite different than .Net's and I understand that well, but in my perspective, I see lot of redundancies and lack of standards(Solid) when developing application in Django. So I came up with my own best standard.

Here is my project hierarchy.

```
 [DjangoProject]:
    [Finance]:
       admin.py
       apis.py
       services.py
       test.py
       urls.py
       models.py
    [Users]:...
```

apis.py -> Each API will have it's one class

```
class ReportCreateApi(APIView):
    class InputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        title = serializers.CharField()
        description = serializers.CharField()
        pictures = serializers.CharField()
        lat = serializers.CharField()
        long = serializers.CharField()
        vote = serializers.CharField()

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.InputSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        ReportService.ireport_create(**serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

services.api -> Services will have **kwargs as parameters

```
class ReportService:
    @staticmethod
    def ireport_create(**report) -> Report:

        logger.info('Creating IReport')

        ireport = Report(**report) #Report is a modal btw
        ireport.save()
        return ireport
```

Although it works for now, it doesn't look right to me. With this anyone can pass unlimited number of parameters that may not be expected by the services.

What would be the best approach to pass the parameters to the `service` from `api` so that I can map it to the model when creating one inside the service?

**PS: .Net example**

```cs
/*"Finance" as a domain layer*/
public class BookKeeping
{
    private String aVariable{get; set;}

    public void doAccounts(TakeInputDto input)
    {
        //Doing something productive
    }
}

/*"GatewayAPI" as API layer*/
public class FinanceAPI: Controller
{
    //Constructor with dependency Injection is here not you can't see it.

    public void CalculateTax()
    {
        _bookKeeping.doAccounts(Dto will take some accepted values)
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent of the `TakeInputDto` in Python?

Comment: FWIW, nested classes (`ReportCreateApi.InputSerializer`) are often misapplied, they're hardly "a thing" in Python. Also, wrapping things in classes which don't need wrapping (`ReportService.ireport_create`) is also not very pythonic.

Comment: `ReportService.ireport_create` can basically be replaced entirely by `Report.objects.create`, both do the same thing.

Comment: Sure, that can directly be in the `apis.py` but it doesn't separate the business logic from api. that's why I have created a service layer. any domain specific logic will go there. Also it can be more that just `Report.objects.create`

Comment: *"With this anyone can pass unlimited number of parameters"* — Well, your calling code can, but not arbitrary users. `ReportService.ireport_create` is a very low level function, again, hardly different from the raw `Report.objects.create`. Somewhere on the very low level, of course you'll want to be able to pass any and all arguments. It's up to the user facing code further up to not allow invalid input, which here is done with `InputSerializer`. So, I'm not sure I understand the concern really.

Comment: Yes, as far as user facing interface is concerned, InputSerializer will take care of filtered inputs which will not allow anything other than specified. In .Net, between service layer and API layer whether a user is carefully passing the parameters to the calling function or not, the calling function will always validate the inputs. So again, my problem here is that **kwargs, will accept any number of parameters, I just want to declare that it can only acceptable parameters nothing else, Ex: .`ireport_create(report: Report)` <- Report Model

Comment: Well, you have written this extremely flexible function yourself. Django's facilities are Serializers and/or Models. Models are the raw data structure obviously accepting anything defined on them, while Serializers are the more limited option. You can of course define `report: Report` as an argument, but that doesn't do the same thing, and I doubt it would in .NET. You'll have to clarify with a more concrete example what facility of .NET in particular you're missing here.

Comment: Updated the question, please take a look in the PS section. 

"What is the equivalent of the `TakeInputDto` in Python?"

Comment: @Kirk What did you decide on TakeInputDto, I have also a similar question?